# Could not load file or assembly Tridion.Extensions.ContextExpressions.Common after upgrade to Tridion Sites 9.6

Tags: publishing, sites-9.6

We have recently upgraded our Tridion environment from Web 8.5 to Tridion Sites 9.6. While Publishing old pages we are getting below error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.Extensions.ContextExpressions.Common, Version=8.1.0.187, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Since the Context Expressions feature is discontinued now how to fix this error?

Comment: Do you actually need it? If it is discontinued, I guess it needs to be removed from your config.

Comment: can you please explain bit more detail which upgrade path you took? did you install it in the 8.5 setup did you upgrade to the same server? or a separate dedicated server you install the 9.5?

Answer (score 5):

It is discontinued, and yes you should remove it. You are using it in the Default finish action Template building block. You need to reload the default template building blocks after the upgrade to 9.6. I had the same situation.
Please follow this link:

**Procedure**

```
Start Template Builder by selecting Start > RWS Group > Template Builder from the Windows menu.

Select Tools > Create Default Building Blocks to load the default Template Building Blocks.

Select a location for the default Template Building Blocks and click OK.
```

https://docs.rws.com/986894/103312/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/loading-template-building-blocks